# Grammatical structure in “best avoided”

Tags: grammar

I come across some phrases such as “best avoided,” or “better avoided.” I understand what it means, but don’t know how this phrase was made. What grammatical structure is in this? I thought this phrase is short for “is best (when it is) avoided,” but this underatanding is just based on my rudimentary grammar. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would say it relates to constructions like *you'd better go now*. To me at least, *X is best avoided* does not mean *X is best when it is avoided*. It means *it is best to avoid X* / *the best thing you can do is avoid X* / *you'd be better-advised to avoid X* etc. Sometimes there is hardly any difference between this meaning and the meaning *X is best when*, e.g. *pizzas are best cooked in the oven* can mean *the best way to cook pizzas...* or *pizzas come out best when...* Sometimes though it can only really have the *it's best to* meaning.

Comment: For example in *Leicester is best avoided*, Leicester is pretty much the same whether it is avoided or not, so this can only really mean *the best thing to do is...* In fact, on the *X is best when it is avoided* reading, this would mean something like *please don't come to Leicester, we're better off without you*, which can't be the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In your case 'best' is an adverb form which is used to modify a verb.

Here's an extract from the entry in Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/best):

***best***

superlative of WELL

1: in the best way

: to greatest advantage

// Some things are best left unsaid.

The same thing is with 'better':

***better***

comparative of WELL

1a: in a more excellent manner
// sings better than I do

b: to greater advantage
 :PREFERABLY
// some things are better left unsaid

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/better)